# New column / mutate based on existing column

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I want to add a new column to a dataframe df based on a condition from the existing columns e.g.,

```
df$TScore = as.factor(0)
df$TScore = 
  if_else(df$test_score >= '8.0', 'high',
      if_else(!is.na(df$test_score), 'low', 'NA'))
```

The problem I am facing is, for some cases TScore is what I would expect it to be i.e., 'high' when the score is 8 or greater but for some cases it is not correct.
Is there an error in the above code? There are lots of NAs in this data.

I am also struggling with how to write it using dplyr(). So far, I have written this:

```
df$TScore =   df %>%
                filter(test_score >= 8) %>%
                    mutate(TScore = 'high')
```

But as we would expect, the dimensions do not match. Following error is given:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, appScore, value = list(cluster3 = c(1L,  : replacement has 126 rows, data has 236
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to do the `filter`, insted can use `ifelse` or `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%           
          mutate(TScore = case_when(test_score >= 8 ~'high', TRUE ~ "low"))
```

if we need to avoid the assignment `<`, can use the compound operator (`%<>%` from `magrittr`

```
library(magrittr)
df %<>%
     mutate(TScore = case_when(is.na(test_score) ~ NA_character_, 
                               test_score >= 8 & !is.na(test_score) ~'high', 
                    TRUE ~ "low"))
```

---

The error occurred because of assigning a `filtered` data.frame to a new column in the original dataset

Comment: Many thanks @akrun. Could you also please advise what to do about the NAs? 
Right now the code masks everything (smaller than 8) as a 'low'.

Comment: @Sadiaz. So, you meant to return `NA` if the value is `NA` right

Comment: Yes return NA when the value is NA

Comment: works perfectly, many thanks!
How should I practice if I want to polish my skills in R - could you please recommend something?

Comment: @Sadiaz Practice can be done only with `practice` :=). Spend at least 1-2 hours daily with patience and tackle problems.  I can't specify a single method that works for everybody because we are all different.  For me, if I  do tackle problems from a book, or solve problems from a course, I get bored.  For others, it may work great.  SO is a great platform to get some instant response and if you are that kind of person who would not mind getting challenged, and taunted